# Disable POST htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

We have a customer's site that is being abused right now via many post attempts made to malicious files uploaded via exploits. We've tried and tried to help the client, but they keep dropping the ball. At this point we are wanting to deny ALL POST attempts made to the site.

I have done this in the past easily, by using the following snippet in the root .htaccess file:

```
<Limit POST HEAD>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
```

However for some reason this time it's causing the entire site to present a 403 forbidden error. Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong? Also if it helps, the site is running WordPress so I have appended the above mentioned code to both the top of the .htaccess file as well as the bottom. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of apache? Newer versions (2.4) don't use the `order` or `allow/deny` directives but instead now use the `require` directive from [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html).

Comment: My apologies! `Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4`

Comment: Just did a quick search and found someone saying that "HEAD" is implied by "GET". Which I take to mean that a "GET" request also makes a "HEAD" request. Maybe just change the limit to `limit POST`. There is no reason why you would want to limit head as well if you are only trying to deny post.

Comment: You could also likely go the other direction and `order allow,deny/allow from all/<limitexcept GET>deny from all</limitexcept>` (/=newline) which will deny anything *not* a get request.

Comment: Be mindful that WordPress has makes `POST` requests natively. Disabling them entirely could cause problems with WordPress.